# Adding Install script and new drop down field in Page CMS

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, fieldsets

Ok so been trying for a couple of days now, I have written a small module to include a dropdown for CMS PAGES in magento.

The dropdown is to allow me to include and exclude pages from a sitemap.

So my scripts are as such:
/app/code/local/Damian/CMS/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <damian_cms>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version of module -->
        </damian_cms>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <damiancms>
                <class>Damian_CMS_Model</class>
            </damiancms>
        </models>
        <events>
            <adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form>
                <observers>
                    <damian_page_edit_tab_content>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Damian_CMS_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>cmsField</method>
                    </damian_page_edit_tab_content>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form>


<cms_page_prepare_save>
    <observers>
        <damian_cms_save_page>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Damian_CMS_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>savePage</method>
        </damian_cms_save_page>
    </observers>
</cms_page_prepare_save>

<cms_page_save_after>
    <observers>
        <damian_cms_save_page_after>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Damian_CMS_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>savePage</method>
        </damian_cms_save_page_after>
    </observers>
</cms_page_save_after>


        </events>


<!--         <resources>
                <setup>
                    <module>Damian_CMS</module>
                                <class>Damian_CMS_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
        </resources> -->

    <resources>  
        <cms_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>damiancms</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </cms_setup>
        <cms_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </cms_write>
        <cms_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </cms_read>
    </resources>



    </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Damian/CMS/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class Damian_CMS_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function cmsField($observer)
    {
        $model = Mage::registry('cms_page');
        $form = $observer->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('damian_content_fieldset', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('cms')->__('Include in Sitemap'),'class'=>'fieldset-wide'));


$fieldset->addField('cms_sitemap', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Select'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'cms_sitemap',
          'onclick' => "",
          'onchange' => "",
          'value'  => '1',
          'values' => array('-1'=>'Please Select..','1' => 'Yes','2' => 'No'),
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => false,
          'after_element_html' => '<small>Select "No" to not include in sitemap</small>',
          'tabindex' => 1
        ));
    }


public function cms_page_prepare_save(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $requestParams = $observer->getRequest()->getParams(); 
        $page = $observer->getPage();
        $page->setData('cms_sitemap',$requestParams); // save the request data to the page model. This will not intevere with normal model functionality as it will be ignored by anything else.
        echo "is this working?";
        print_r("test before save:::: ".$this);

        return $this;
    }


public function cms_page_save_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) { 
        $page = $observer->getObject();
        $requestParams = $page->getRequestParams();
           echo "is working?";

        print_r("test after save:::: ".$this);
                return $this;
    }

}
?>
```

/app/code/local/Damian/CMS/sql/cms_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

echo 'Running This Upgrade: '.get_class($this)."\n <br /> \n";
die("Exit for now");    

$installer->startSetup();

$conn = $installer->getConnection();

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('cms_page'),'cms_sitemap', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'length'    => 255,
        'comment'   => '1= yes 2=no'
        ));   




$installer->endSetup();
```

/app/etc/modules/Damian_CMS.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Damian_CMS>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Damian_CMS>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Ok so i think that is everything, this is my first module and your help is much appreciated...

Comment: Anybody out there who can help?

Answer (score 0):

For now i have manually updated the CMS_PAGE table and played around with updating the data, which it works, 
I just had to add this to the first link in the observer (class Damian_CMS_Model_Observer  extends Varien_Event_Observer)

But i am still not sure how to do an update script, anyone can help?